# (Done) Reopen "Is there any feasible way to avoid outing myself as transgender to prospective employers?"

Tags: discussion, reopen-request

Recently, my question "[Is there any feasible way to avoid outing myself as transgender to prospective employers?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/190304/85361)" was closed as needing more focus, with the close notice telling me to

> Update the question so it focuses on one problem only.

and encouraging me to either edit the existing question so that it focusses on a single problem, or post a new, revised question that focusses on a single problem.

However, the question *already* focusses on a single problem (namely, how - or *if* - I can avoid outing myself as transgender to potential employers when applying or interviewing), and, as such, I'm at a loss as to why it was closed.<sup>1</sup>  Could someone reopen the aforementioned question, please?

---

<sup>1</sup>: For that matter, I also don't get why the question was kicked off HNQ less than four hours after it arrived there.  Job-hunting while trans doesn't seem like it'd be a topic that'd garner that sort of reaction...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Could someone reopen the aforementioned question, please?

You are the OP. I see that you got several answers and help, and that **you even accepted one of those answers.**

This tells me that your question was satisfied and that the help you asked for was given. Thus, you have no need for further answers, otherwise you wouldn't have accepted that one.

Why ask for your question to be reopened then if you already accepted an answer?

---

Edit: I reviewed the question and found that the reason "needs focus" was invalid. Thus, I reopened it.

Anyways, you still got good answers there and even accepted one. I suggest you move on, as having a question closed/opened is not a hill to die on IMHO.

Comment: Because "it's been answered to the asker's satisfaction" is not one of our close reasons, and the close reason that was given is manifestly invalid.

Comment: On another note @Vikki I read the question and... I find it ok and focused. Don't know why it was closed, sometimes people here are trigger-happy (due to the gamification of SE I think, in part). Regarding the removal of HNQ, I didn't handle that, but if I had to guess on the intentions of the mod that did it, it was because HNQ tends to attrack low quality answers and sometimes trolls. Removing it form HNQ help avoid that and to avoid having your question Derailed.

Comment: @Vikki thus I will hammer it open. Just wanted to know your reasons for *why* reopen it if you already accepted an answer. Because, if you already got help and it was useful, it's better to thank for it and move on... unless... judging (and guessing) by your emphasis on the HNQ removal, you wanted it open so you could gather some extra reps (which, again, is due to the gamification of SE and reputation)... anyways I don't see it as "needs focus", and no Mod voted to close it... so I'll hammer it Open and wait to see what others have to say.

Comment: Of the several of my questions make it onto HNQ (most of them, IIRC, from Aviation.SE, the stack where I'm most-active), I don't recall any having been badly derailed or having had an unbearable level of low-quality answers, which personally makes it feel (especially given the subject matter of this particular question) less like a safeguard and more like I'm being silenced.  And I'm _not_ (primarily) asking that it be reopened in order to get extra reputation, but, rather, because seeing questions closed that objectively shouldn't've been _really_ sticks in my craw... (1/2)

Comment: (2/2) ...especially since (again), given the question's subject matter, the objectively-unjustified nature of the closure carries uncomfortable undertones of silencing.  (Thanx for reopening, BTW.)

Comment: @Vikki here in TWP we deal with more sensitive/human/derail-able topics than, perhaps, on Aviation SE. HNQ is delicate matter here, as it attracts people from everywhere onto a Question that almost everybody "feels" they are capable of answering... it's not like I see a HNQ from Aviation, navigate to it and magically decide I have something to say (I'm not knowledgeable on aviation)... but as we deal with more human/social topics things are different here.

Comment: Mmm, makes sense.

Comment: I disagree with the concept that once the OP accepts an answer there are no need for other answers. I believe questions should stay open to solicit even better answers that may appear in the future, and may help other people.

Answer (score 4):

I see DarkCygnus has already addressed the closure issue (and re-opened it) so I won't add to that other than to say I agree 100%.

> For that matter, I also don't get why the question was kicked off HNQ less than four hours after it arrived there. Job-hunting while trans doesn't seem like it'd be a topic that'd garner that sort of reaction...

I was the mod who removed it from HNQ - The HNQ removal was in no way a criticism of yourself or your question, or any attempt to silence you. My reasoning was absolutely one of preventing the question being derailed into unpleasantness. The particular subject matter of the question (nothing to do with *you*) has previous form for producing that sort of effect - I wish it weren't so but it is.

Even before it HNQ there were some undesirable comments that had (rightfully) attracted multiple flags and once it did there was at least one incident that I dealt with of a HNQ visitor misusing flags in an attempt to be disruptive so I would rather take action at the first signs of trouble than wait for it to (potentially) get worse.

*After* I removed it from HNQ, the question (from what I saw) continued on in a healthy way with largely constructive interactions, and I don't think I saw another flag raised  which I think serves as some validation of the steps taken.

Comment: A good summary on most people's stance on HNQ here. In my experience it adds a ton of noise both in the forms of comments and off-the-cuff answers. Particularly around subjects related to discrimination, fairness, and other loaded topics, the answers given by "drive-by" HNQ users often trend towards the facile. All too often people answer based on how they think the world ought to work, without realising that they're giving advice that can be harmful to someone's career. Our topics often impact people's livelihoods, not just the next software build or provide idle trivia.